# Microphone doesn't work with Skype and pulseaudio

Tags: pulseaudio, skype

The microphone doesn't work with Skype.
When I delete `pulseaudio` from the system the microphone works well, but in this case the audio disappears in the browsers. Audio works with Skype, works with media player, but not with browser.

So I can use somes one: or microphone with Skype, or audio with browser. How to use both?

Answer (score 0):

The microphone doesn't work with Skype. I see this issue Skype has been debating for years. What's wrong with Skype?

In my case, only Skype alone does not work with the microphone of both (1) the webcam and (2) the headset. All other applications work, for example the simple app Audio Recorder and the complex app OBS Studio. Their work from the microphone is visible on the Record tab in Pulse Audio, and only for Skype this tab is empty.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Your answer seems to be a comment more than anything else. Perhaps you could move it under Valentyn’s question instead?